# C# logged user and run as user

Tags: c#

I have 2 users:  domain1\user1  and domain2\user2.
I'm logged with domain1\user1. I want to run app (with option 'Run as different user') with domain2\user2.
How can I gets the user name of the person who is currently logged on to the Windows, because Environment.UserName return user2, but I want domain1\user1.

Answer (score 4):

Check out `WindowsImpersonationContext` on MSDN, I believe it has what you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx

You can implement your own helper class if you like, then declare `using([establish your context here])` and perform your activities within that code block that will be executed with that user context.  Quite handy!

Note: If you decide to utilize `using`, be sure in the `Dispose()` method of your helper that you release the impersonation context so that everything cleans up nicely when your program leaves the `using` block.